# Trying to create a list by passing a index from another list

Tags: python, list, append

Python 3.11 using Jupyter Lab

There is an original list (my_family) of family members.  The user is asked to type in a name of a member of that list.  The user input returns the index for the name in the list.

The goal is to add that name to a new list (removed_family) using the index we just gathered.

```
my_family = ['Chuck', 'Donna', 'Tammy', 'Barb', 'Sean', 'Chance', 'Gabe']

removed_person = input('Type the name of the person to remove from your family')

removed_index = my_family.index(removed_person)

print(removed_person)

print(removed_index)

removed_family = [my_family(removed_index)]

print(removed_family)

Type the name of the person to remove from your family Sean

Sean
4

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[102], line 6
      4 print(removed_person)
      5 print(removed_index)
----> 6 removed_family = [my_family(removed_index)]
      7 print(removed_family)

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I tried using the input from the user to create the list.  I tried creating an empty list by setting it equal to '[]' and appending.

I tried using, "removed_family.append(my_family(removed_index))", but since removed family was never created it cannot be appended.  The error is "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"

Comment: List indexing is done with `[]`, not `()`. But why access it as `my_family[removed_index]` when you know that the name at that index is `removed_person`?

Comment: The linked duplicate is unfortunately difficult to find because, ironically, it seems to be *shadowed* by the other common cause of this error, shadowing the built-in name `list`. I think downvoting this is harsh, as far as questions go, this at least provided a [mcve]

Comment: I did try to use the name of the person, but had problems, so I tried using the index.  I thought that maybe you had to use the index for this to work.  I also tried using [] and ().  I can't seem to get any of it to work.

Comment: @Tim you aren't understanding.  The immediate cause of your error is that you are trying to **call the list**, as the error message explains. You are doing `removed_family = [my_family(removed_index)]`, so you are trying to *call the list* when you do `my_family(removed_index)`, but you need `my_family[removed_index]`, with square brackets (you need to *index* the list, not call it). But the point that is being made is that you *already have that object*, you can just do `removed_family = [removed_person]`

Comment: I see it now.  Thanks for the input.  I also change it to "removed_family = [removed_person]" and that worked even better.

Answer (score -1):

for adding item to list you can use `append` function.

[See this page, it will definitely help you](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_append.asp)

and also you can try this to add item to your list:

```
removed_family.append(my_family(removed_index))
```

Comment: this doesn't address the error *at all*

Comment: I tried this.  I created an empty list "removed_family = []".  Then I added the append line you have "removed_family.append(my_family(removed_index))", but I get this error "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable".

Comment: `mylist = []; mylist.append(x)` is equivalent to `mylist = [x]` anyway